# How to change style of ternary operator based on the word?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following :

```
<td>${person.gender ? 'Male' : 'Female'}</td>
```

I want to add some style that will make the text Blue when the work is "Male" and pink when the word is "Female".

I want to do this with javascript, not using an external .css file.

Is this possible?

Comment: You will have to put a `<span>` around the text that you can style, or put the style on the td based on what the gender is.

Comment: @Taplar ah sorry nm i think i get what you mean

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework here? You could perhaps use the same `${person.gender ? "blue" : "pink"}` type construct elsewhere, depending on which one you're using...

Comment: @Taplar when attempting to use span male and female no longer get displayed

Comment: Show us what you tried?  Edit: by putting a span around the text, I hope you did not interpret that as replacing the td with a span.  That was not the intention.  It would be in addition to the td.

Comment: @Taplar `<td>${person.gender ? <span style="color:blue"> 'Male' </span> : 'Female'}</td>`

Comment: Ok, you're issue is a syntax issue.  It needs to be `'<span style="color:blue">Male</span>'` with the single quotes around the whole string.

Comment: @Taplar I thought that may have been the issue however, now rather than displaying Male or Female the following is displayed : `${person.gender ? 'Male' : 'Female'}` and **('Male' is blue)**

Comment: `<td>${person.gender ? '<span style="color:blue">Male</span>' : '<span style="color:pink">Female</span>'}</td>` <= you did that?

Comment: @Taplar yes, this almost works. It changes the colors but also displays the `${person.gender ? 'Male' : 'Female'}` part on the webpage, rather than just the Male or Female

Comment: That should not be displaying the logic if it is in that form.

Comment: @Taplar I have done it the exact same way as you have shown

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking about doing something like this in vanilla JavaScript here is how you can do it -

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(val => {
  val.style.color = val.innerText.toLowerCase() == "male" ? "blue" : "hotpink";
})
```

```html
<p>Male</p>
<p>Female</p>
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't seem to work. I feel like Taplar gave a close solution but I can get it to work as wanted.